# Looking to boost radio signal around the house

Tags: electrical, wiring

The set up is that my house is located in a valley.  If I try and use a standard fm radio I get terrible reception.

There is an areal mounted on a pole at the side of the valley that receives good fm, which comes down via a Coaxial Cable to the house. If I plug this into a radio
I get great reception.

I would like to plug this cable into one point in the house and have it transmitted wireless to multiple fm radios in the house.  Is this possible?

I know that I can get an fm distribution amplifier, but all the ones of these I've seen are cabled, (one coax in, 4+ out) so I would have to wire all the rooms with a coax point.

Another option that I've considered is getting several internet radios and just playing off the wifi. (lets call this plan B!)

I've also looked at a few FM transmitters, but and while I can plug these into various devices, I haven't found one that takes a Coax cable and re transmits.

The last thing I saw that might do the job is an FM Translator which is meant to rebroadcast the signal of a primary AM or FM station on a different frequency.  Although I haven't found much information on these yet or figured out where to buy one!

So that's the setup, and some of the things I've looked at.  I'm wondering is there any easy option I'm missing, or if anyone could advise what they've done in similar situations?

Comment: The reason you can't rebroadcast successfully on the same frequency is called ghosting. That is the original signal plus the rebroadcast signal will never be in sync, the solution is to rebroadcast on a different frequency.  Back in the days of analog TV and analog cable rebroadcasting this is the EXACT reason that cable channel numbering differed from OTA broadcast channel numbering.  You best solution is plan B... WiFi streaming.

Comment: I used to use a cheap am transmitter, I picked up the radio signal in the house and found a am transmitter that ran off a 9v battery I tuned the radio in the shop to the am signal and could pick up the channel that was playing in the house, radio or audio books it worked well, I had to change the battery every 6-9 months. It was like a Mr. Microphone but made for relaying an audio signal on am.

Comment: @EdBeal what did you use to pick up the fm Radio and send it to the am transmitter?  I had considered a cheap the one radio with a good signal, and having it broadcast via a fm transmitter on a different frequency, but it seemed very limited

Comment: @EdBeal, the bandwidth of an AM radio channel is much less than the bandwidth of an FM channel.  If your cheap AM transmitter does not filter the signal to fit, then the AM receiver will.  Either way, you're turning a Hi-Fi stereo program into a Lo-Fi, mono program.  OK for talk maybe, but not very satisfactory for music.

Comment: I think they also make an fm version the am was fine for what I listened to.

Comment: you could always listen to the station through an internet connection